# Can we get an easy, markdownish way to color text?

Tags: feature-request

Recently, while posting a question, I realized that it would have been handy to be able to color-code some of the text in my post. I think we should have a way, using markdown, to do this easily. Only a few colors would be needed, but HTML colors should be allowed too. It would be nice to be able to color monospaced font, as we probably won't be using it for code.

Comment: Could you link to the question you asked and point out which bits would be color coded? (Also, I won't consider this request if you don't upvote the [footnote Markdown suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5017/1438). ;-)

Comment: @JonEricson I had a picture, and I was pointing out different parts of the picture.

Comment: Only if we get a button to stab users who abuse it in the face.

Answer (score 9):

[image: no]

---

(my point being that colors are <red>ridiculously</red> easy to abuse and would quickly get <green>annoying</green> and make us look like a <blue>forum</blue>.)

Comment: That's an argument against color _gradients_. ;-)

Comment: @Jon This isn't a gradient; each letter is its own color.

Comment: Hmmm... The 'b' in terrible is a wonderful illusion then.

Comment: @Jon Indeed it is. (Try inspecting it with an image editor)

Comment: But color-coding is handy!

Answer (score 4):

You can have coloured text in MathJax, as per the [MathJax tutorial on Mathematics.SE's Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10116)<sup>†</sup>. These do not render in all browsers; I can see the colours in Chrome, but not in IE9.

<sup>†: Perhaps we should permalink this from our help section, or was that done already?</sup>

Comment: $\color{fuchsia}{\mathbb{OMG!}}$

Comment: @AE That even works for me in IE9.

Answer (score -1):

Since SQB has pointed out that MathJax can be used in this way in an answer to this question, can I suggest that we do the opposite of what the Doctor wanted? Can we disallow less universally needed MathJax commands till a user has a certain reputation threshold?

MathJax makes a lot of great math puzzles possible, but features like color and font could be exploited by new users to create some truly eyeviscerating puzzle challenges. Those extra features could also be used by experienced users to create awesome puzzles from time to time, so they shouldn't be removed completely. I suggest that $$ \Bbb{FONTS},\ \color{green}{colors},\ \text{and}\ \backslash newcommand$$ be disallowed for users under 500 rep.